# Diferencia entre arrow function y function normal al llamar al método subscribe Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Tengo un servicio declarado en angular con el método getSomeData() en la que recojo datos de un json tal que así:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/filter";

@Injectable()
export class GetDataService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getSomeData() {
    return this.http.get("dataTable.json")
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

En el componente tengo una variable `data : any;` para pintar los datos en el template.

Al llamar al subscribirse al servicio en el componente con una función normal de javascript tal que así, no me muestra los datos con la respuesta.

```
ngOnInit():void {
   this._service.getSomeData().subscribe(
        function(response) { this.data = JSON.stringify(response) },
        function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
        function() { console.log("the subscription is completed")}
   );
}
```

Sin embargo si llamo al método subscribe con una Arrow Function si me pinta los datos:

```
 ngOnInit():void {
    this._service.getSomeData().subscribe(
          response=>{
           this.data = JSON.stringify(response);
          }
          err=>{
              console.log("Error happened" + error)
          }
    );
 }
```

Pienso que es un tema de asincronia ya que con funciones normales no le da tiempo a pintar los datos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La diferencia entre una función flecha (arrow function) y una normal es el contexto: En las funciones clásicas el contexto se define al llamarlas y en las funciones flechas se define al declararlas. Nada mejor que un ejemplo para verlo claro:

```js
(function() {

this.b="otra cosa";
this.a="una cosa"

function MiClase() {
  this.a="hola";
  this.b="adios";
}

let obj= new MiClase();
let getA=function () {
  return this.a;
};

obj.getA=getA;

let getB=() => this.b;
obj.getB=getB;

console.log(getA());
console.log(getB());

console.log(obj.getA());
console.log(obj.getB());

})();
```

Explicación: getA es una función normal, por tanto si se llama como a una función, `this` es el contexto en el que se llama, pero si se llama como método, `this` es el objeto al que pertenece el método.

En cambio, getB es una función flecha, por tanto `this` siempre es el contexto en el que fue declarada.

En tu caso, como tus funciones se declaran cuando el contexto es tu clase `GetDataService`, `this` apuntará al la instancia de `GetDataService`, mientras que las funciones tradicionales this será el contexto del observable, con lo que `this.data` no se puede asignar porque no existe.

¿Cómo hacer que las funciones "clásicas" funcionen en este escenario? Hay dos soluciones:

```js
//por defecto el contexto es el objeto global (window)
console.log(this===window);

window.test="esto es un test";

let obj={
  test: "Atributo de obj"
}

function getTest1(){
  return this.test;
}

let self=this;
function getTest2(){
//closure (clausura): hemos guardado el contexto en una variable accesible por la función
  return self.test;
}



obj.test1=getTest1;
obj.test2=getTest2;
obj.test3=getTest1.bind(window);
//bind devuelve una función con el contexto fijado al parámetro que se le pase

console.log(obj.test1());
console.log(obj.test2());
console.log(obj.test3());
```