# React Navigation no redirige a otra pantalla luego de validar usuario con axios

Tags: react-native, axios, react-navigation

Este es mi código de validación

***EDITADO***

```
    _onpressbutton = async () => {

  axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://equalshost.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/api/auth/login',
        data: {
          username: this.state.user,
          password: this.state.pass
        }
      }).then(function(response){
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');

  }).catch(function(error){
  console.log(error);
  });
}
```

como veran cuando en mi button llamo la funcion onpressbutton este valida cn axios el usuario, cuando es correcto deberia redirigir a la pantalla menu pero no realiza nada, se que esta bien porque me devuelve el token por lo que llega al "then"  esto son mis imports

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  Alert,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  AppRegistry,
  ImageBackground,

} from 'react-native';
import { TextField } from 'react-native-material-textfield';
import { Button , Text} from 'native-base'
```

**EDITADO:**

este es mi appNavigator.js

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/Login';

const Login = createStackNavigator({ Login: LoginScreen }) 

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
  // You could add another route here for authentication.
  // Read more at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html
  Inicial : Login,
  Main: MainTabNavigator,
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Inicial',
}

));
```

Comment: Te arroja algún error? Si entra al `then` y no ejecuta el cambio de pantallas, te recomiendo que edites la pregunta e incluyas tu archivo donde defines tus rutas o pantallas

Comment: entra al .then pero no redirige creo que no "considera" el navegation por el axios pero estoy especulando porque no tengo certeza, porque por ejemplo comente todo lo referente a axios y solo deje el navegation redirigiendo y si me redirigio a la pantalla que queria, actualizare donde defino las pantallas, soy nuevo en react native

Comment: Proba haciendo lo siguiente: var context = this; (antes de la llamada axios) y en el then, en lugar de this, usa esa variable context...

Comment: Ya entiendo qué te sucede, lo que pasa es que no entiendo por qué no te arroja error. Pero me parece que tienes un error con los closures. Intenta cambiar el `function` por un `arrow function`, es decir: `.then((response) => {}` para no perder el scope

Comment: @GermanAlzate me dio este error ahora =>
**
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')
* screens\Login.js:37:17 in <unknown>
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals**

Comment: la linea 37 es donde tengo el   =>    this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');

Comment: Intentaste como te propuso @gbianchi en el comentario?

Comment: Muchas Gracias @gbianchi eso resolvio mi problema, porque ocurre eso amigo me podria explicar? muchas gracias a los dos

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias

Comment: Tambien ver: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/101929/324